How to make Isolation Forest detect anomaly at the peak of the difference, instead of the first value seen
I am using Isolation Forest to identify anomalies in a very large data frame. The data is noisy, so I have conducted many filtering operations to smooth out the noise so that the true anomalies present in the data stand out. I then used .diff() on this data set to create a straight line that spikes when an anomaly occurs. Isolation Forest is then used to identify these anomalies.
My issue is that Isolation Forest is identifying the anomaly at the earliest point it can detect an anomaly from occurring, but I need it to detect it at the peak difference.
df["Ref Wt. Denoised"] = denoise(df["Ref Wt."].values, level=2)
df["Ref Wt. Savgol"] = apply_savgol_filter(df["Ref Wt. Denoised"], window_length=101, polyorder=3)
df["Ref Wt. Smoothed"] = df["Ref Wt. Savgol"].rolling(window=indexer).mean()
df["Ref Wt. Diff"] = df["Ref Wt. Smoothed"].diff(periods=300).fillna(0)

df["WOB Anomaly"] = detect_wob.predict(df["Ref Wt. Diff"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

df["WOB Zero Event"] = df["WOB Anomaly"] == -1

I have played around using .shift() to fix it, but this manual change works for some values but not all. I really want to avoid changing the window size that I use to smooth the data over because this severely affects accuracy.
Image of Issue and Fix I'm Looking For

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you could define a threshold, there's a potential for you to find the peaks and then test for an anomaly given a set of peaks:
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(df["Ref Wt. Diff"], height=threshold)  
df["Peak Indicator"] = 0  # init the Peak Indicator column
df.loc[peaks, "Peak Indicator"] = 1  # Mark the peaks
peak_data = df[df["Peak Indicator"] == 1]
if not peak_data.empty:
    df["WOB Anomaly"] = np.nan  # init anomaly column
    df.loc[peak_data.index, "WOB Anomaly"] = detect_wob.predict(peak_data["Ref Wt. Diff"].values.reshape(-1, 1))


This is hard, because each peak is a different size so this threshold would need to be dynamic instead of a stagnant value. The program as of now detects anomalies each time the .diff() graph has a significant spike (or peak), but it does not mark the anomaly at the apex of this peak, rather at the beginning of the slope. The timing is just off

It sounds like the timing is good and bad: good because it's classifying the beginning of the anomalous event, but bad because it doesn't identify peak anomaly or duration.  I thought Isolation Forest would have flagged most of the event you have pictured as anomolous.  Can you share how you initialized your isolation forest object (is it from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest )

Yes, that's exactly right and that is how I initialize it. I suppose the ML algorithm is doing exactly what it should be doing- identifying the first point that an anomaly occurs. I just need it to place this anomaly at the point that is most like an anomaly (the peak, in this case) instead of the first instance it becomes one.
